# Question on part 3 of the Star Trek problem in Williams, Probability with Martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

Consider [this M.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175348/the-star-trek-problem-in-williamss-book), which is E12.3 in Williams. The answer of Robert Israel (and Xoff) seems to give an exponential bound on $R_n$ almost surely. Wouldn't this imply the convergence of 
$$\sum R_n^{-1},$$
which is significantly stronger than what the problem asks to prove, which is the convergence of 
$$\sum R_n^{-2}?$$

I would like confirmation that this stronger result is actually true and that I am not missing anything.

Comment: This is correct. Robert Israel's answer completely describes the matter; however, one should refer to the law of large numbers rather than to the central limit theorem. If you want, I can try to elaborate a bit.

Comment: @zhoraster That would be great! Then I can accept your answer and take this off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the ship after $n$ space-hops is${}^*$ $X_{n} = X_{n-1} + R_{n-1} U_n$, where the vector $V_n$ is independent of $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$ and uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S_1$. So $R_n = R_{n-1}|e_{n-1}+V_n|$, where $e_{n-1}$ is a unit vector in the direction of $X_{n-1}$. Then, clearly, $R_n= R_{n-2}|e+U_{n-1}||e+U_n| = R\prod_{k=1}^n |e+U_k|,$ where $e$ is a fixed unit vector, and $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_k$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $S_1$. In order to study the asymptotic behavior of $R_n$, it is easier to consider its logarithm: 
$$
\log R_n = \log R + \sum_{k=1}^n \log |e+U_k|.
$$
The latter sum consists of independent identically distributed random variables. Therefore, in view of the strong law of large numbers,
$$
\frac1n \log R_n \to E[\log |e+U_1|], n\to\infty,\tag{1}
$$
almost surely. Now
$$
E[\log |e+U_1|] = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S_1} \log|e+v| d\sigma(v);
$$
taking $e = (0,0,-1)$ and parametrizing $S_1$ by $v = (\cos \varphi \sin \theta,  \sin\varphi \sin \theta, \cos\theta)$, we get $|e+v| = \sqrt{\sin^2\theta + (\cos\theta-1)^2} = \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$, whence 
$$
E[\log |e+U_1|] = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac12 \sin\theta\log(2-2\cos\theta)d\theta\,d\varphi \\
= \frac14 \int_{-1}^1 \log(2+2x)dx = \log 2 - \frac12>0.
$$
Therefore, in view of (1), for any $c\in(0,\log2-1/2)$, $\log R_n> cn$ eventually with probability 1, equivalently, $R_n> e^{cn}$. Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{R_n}$ converges almost surely.